# How to write a case statement in the Where clause of Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

Please tell me this problem.

```
TABLE:PPP
+-------+---------+---------+----------+
|No     |  Flag_A | Flag_B  |   Qty    |
+-------+---------+---------+----------+
|100    |    P    |    0    |    10    |
|300    |    B    |    1    |    20    |
|500    |    C    |    0    |    30    |
|100    |    P    |    0    |    40    |
|100    |    P    |    0    |    50    |
|300    |    B    |    1    |    60    |
|500    |    C    |    1    |    70    |
|100    |    P    |    0    |    80    |
|500    |    B    |    2    |    90    |
+-------+---------+---------+----------+

SELECT NO, SUM(QTY) AS QTY 
  FROM PPP
 WHERE 
   CASE FLAG_B IN (
     WHEN FLAG_A = 'P' THEN '0'
     WHEN FLAG_A = 'C' THEN '1'
     WHEN FLAG_A = 'B' THEN '0' , '1' <- how to write? 
    END
   )
GROUP BY NO
```

I want get this result.

```
+----+-----+
| No | Qty | 
+----+-----+
| 100|  180|
| 300|   80|
| 500|  100|
+----+-----+
```

What should i write sql?

Comment: it seems impossible to get Qty=100 for No=500 ...

Comment: It is odd that a column called "flag" would have a value of "2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be simpler phrased with boolean logic:

```
where (flag_a = 'P' and flag_b = 0)
   or (flag_a = 'C' and flag_b = 1)
   or (flag_a = 'B' and flag_b in (0, 1))
```

We can factorize a little:

```
where (flag_a in ('B', 'P') and flag_b = 0)
   or (flag_a in ('B', 'C') and flag_b = 1)
```

Or we can use tuple equality:

```
where (flag_a, flag_b) in (('P', 0), ('C', 1), ('B', 0), ('B', 1))
```

`flag_b` looks like a number, so I compared it against literal numbers; if that's really a string, then you can add back the single quotes around the literals.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply.
I tried it and it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `DECODE()` function containing `CASE..WHEN` expression in it for the case `flag_a='B'`  might be an alternative way to get the desired results such as

```
SELECT no, SUM(qty) AS qty
  FROM ppp
 WHERE DECODE(flag_a,'P',0,'C',1,'B', CASE WHEN flag_b IN (0,1) THEN flag_b END)=flag_b
 GROUP BY no
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c93c9f8d00c8a925f8fa94008748191e)</kbd>

*P.S: I think there's an issue, which needs to fixed, with the data for `No=500`*